# Java Home issues (JDK INSTALL) - Java Home keeps changing directory by itself so I always get error message java home not set properly

Tags: java, maven, java-home

MAC OS M1
JDK 16.0.2 - using because apparently works better with javafx on m1 mac
no difference with issue with other versions of java

I have followed these steps to set java home

*# check if JAVA_HOME is defined in your Mac OS + M1 chip
@mac ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME

**//When I do this I get results "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Homeeval"**
I then do the below steps

## if no home defined, get the path of java by running the command

```
@mac ~ % /usr/libexec/java_home
```

**My result is "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"**

@mac ~ % export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
@mac ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME
**my result is "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"**

edit - When i try to make a javafx project in vscode as part of trying to install javafx, i get the following error.Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Homeeval/bin/java
I think the fact java home is moving from homeeval to home is messing with something disabling me from making a project

Can someone explain why java home keeps moving?

thanks